# Expiring Provisioning Profile - Enterprise Deployment

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ios-enterprise

Quick sanity check - I've read through several related questions and I'm still confused about this topic.

We have an enterprise application that we deploy using an MDM (Air Watch). Our application certificate is valid for another two years, and our provisioning profile is about to expire in a month.

I have renewed my provisioning profile, and performed the following test -

- Got an iPad with the application installed
- Removed the provisioning profile from Settings > General > Profiles
- Rebooted the iPad and verified that the application would not launch any more.
- Pushed a new provisioning profile onto the iPad using AirWatch
- Launched the app verified that it works.

So, if my understanding is correct, I **do not** need to re-sign and push the whole application out to all our devices. Instead, I just push out a new provisioning profile to all our devices and I should be good to go?

Comment: I'm curious where this ended up for you.

Comment: Any updates on above

Comment: Worked fine actually. As long as the cert you used isn't expiring, you can just push an updated provisioning profile out.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an apple developer account, you can create your own wildcard provisioning profile.

1. Find the app in AW
2. Select it and then select Edit
3. Select files and renew the provision profile
4. At this point, upload your newly created provisioning profile
5. Press save and assign, the provisioning profile will update the app discreetly

hey presto you have another 12 months validation. :D

Comment: Best answer I've found!

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer. What I'm still confused on is what the equivalent is for when your certificate expires.