# Airwatch ad-hoc distribution without generating new IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, airwatch

I maintain an internal iOS app for a client who has an Apple Developer Program account (not Enterprise). They routinely give new devices access to the app by adding the UDIDs to the Devices list in their Apple Developer account and updating their Distribution provisioning profile. Then they deploy the app to the new devices through Airwatch.

When they add new devices in this way, they don't want to have to rebuild the app in Xcode with the updated profile. Instead, they believe they should be able to export the updated profile from their developer account, upload the profile to Airwatch, and push the app to the new devices, without ever generating a new IPA.

**Is it possible to do this without an Enterprise Apple Developer account?**

Comment: It would be better for them to publish the app as a B2B app that they can then distribute via Airwatch

Comment: @Paulw11 interesting idea. Right now I want to see if this can be done with Apple's standard workflow.

Comment: If you don't have an enterprise membership then you cannot create an ipa that will install on any device outside of the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can get the new provisioning profile on the devices through MDM, you don't need to publish a new build.  You just need to make sure the profile is installed on the device before they try to install the app.  iOS doesn't necessarily care if the valid provisioning profile is bundled with the app when it was packaged.  It just cares if a valid provisioning profile is installed on the device when an app is installed / run on the device.

I have used a similar technique with some internal apps we have, since we use a wildcard bundle ID in our profile.  If the profile bundled with app A expires, it doesn't matter as long as the user has installed app B, which has a newer, still valid profile.

In my opinion, the workflow should look like this:

1. new device(s) received
2. add devices to provisioning profile on developer site
3. download updated profile and distribute it to all devices, including new device(s) via MDM
4. have users of new device install app (which should work since they now have a valid profile on their device for the bundle ID in question)

This works for profiles, however, when the certificate expires, you will need to rebuild the app(s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if this workflow is compatible with Airwatch and a standard (non-Enterprise) Apple Dev account?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Airwatch MDM functionality works, but I'm fairly certain that it has the ability to push provisioning profiles to devices that are are managed.  If it can push profiles, there is no significant difference between the enterprise in house provisioning profiles vs a standard account's distribution profile, at least in terms of the installation on a device.

Comment: This is older, but it may provide guidance for workflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34636615/3708242

Comment: After reading through Airwatch's documentation and the other SO answer you referenced, it seems like you need an Apple Enterprise developer account to use the above workflow.

Comment: What do you need the enterprise developer account for? For the management of the device profiles?